# @Query doesn't return any result

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA's @Query annotation in my repository class. When I run same sql in PL-SQL developer it return result but inside application not. What is the problem ? How I can fix it ? pls help . 
Thanks in advance

**My Repo Class:**

```
@Repository
public interface FiberChannelRepository extends FndJpaRepositiry<FiberChannel, Long> {

  @Query("select n.id, c.id, loc from FiberChannel fc  left join Channel c on fc.id=c.id left join ChannelNode cn on c.id = cn.id and cn.deleted != true  left join Node n  on cn.id = n.id and cn.deleted != true  left join Location loc on loc.id = n.id and cn.deleted != true where fc.id=?1")
  List<Object[]> findNodesByFiber_Id(Long idFiber);

}
```

**SQL variant :**

```
select n.id_node, c.id_channel, loc.*
  from Fiber_Channel fc 
      left join channel c on fc.id_channel=c.id_channel  
  left join CHANNEL_NODE cn
      on c.id_channel = cn.id_channel and cn.is_deleted != 1 
  left join Node n 
      on cn.id_node = n.id_node and cn.is_deleted != 1 
  left join Location loc
      on loc.id_location = n.id_location and cn.is_deleted != 1 where 
fc.id_fiber=42266
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem. I made wrong in query sql. I replace  fc.id with fc.fiber.id  and it works now.